# Display PDF on raspberry

Tags: kiosk

I want to program my raspberry such that, when I boot it on, it get's in a sort of folder, where I can choose a PDF file and then it would display it... It should only do that... So a sort of Kiosk mode for PDF visualisation.
I have looked at FullPageOS, but which only seems supporting web pages. I have tried looking at "Impressive" as well, and it seemed a lot more promising, but haven't found out if I could have more than one file...

Could anyone provide me with some help?

Comment: I think you need to detail the user workflow more fully. ie. after the pi boots and shows this folder, are all the pdf files saved locally on the sd card and once the user has viewed a file, are they expecting to be able to close and open another file?

Comment: The two main issues i think you'll run into are that presenting a folder of pdf files is a bit of a risk as the file manager isn't designed to really be locked down to a single folder and users tend to struggle with windows so its likely it'll end up in a bit of a state, how do you ensure that the next user gets the same starting point. Give us a little more detail and i'm sure there's a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something [like zenity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488350/how-do-i-prompt-users-with-a-gui-dialog-box-to-choose-file-directory-path-via-t) to pick the file, then `xpdf -fullscreen` to display it.

```
xpdf -fullscreen "$(zenity --file-selection --file-filter='PDF files (pdf) | *.pdf' --title="Select a PDF file" --filename ~/Documents/)"
```